# My code fails after OS X Mavericks

Tags: python

I have some Python code write on my mac pro running on v2.7, after install Maverick my code fails to run on Dimension module, says that can't find that module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import * 
import tkFont
import Dimension

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        sz = Dimension(200, 200)
        self.size(sz)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        ifont = tkFont.Font(family='Courier New', size=14)

        self.quitButton = Button ( self, text='Quit',
                              command=self.quit , font=ifont)
        self.quitButton.grid()
        self.openButton = Button (self, text='Open', command=self.quit)

        self.openButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.master.title("Sample application")
app.mainloop()
```

error:

```
Ganimedes:python denisbopp$ python tutor_01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tutor_01.py", line 4, in <module>
    import Dimension
ImportError: No module named Dimension
```

Comment: And you are 100% certain you have `Dimension.py` sitting right there in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your `PYTHONPATH` was changed after you upgraded your system. You can do

```
import sys
sys.path
```

to check all the included path, and do

```
sys.path.append('/path /to /the /module')
```

to add a path.

Python will find the module if the module file is in `PYTHONPATH` or in the same directory you executed the script.